# Can I add multiple tracking ids to pinterest tracking javascript

Tags: javascript, pinterest

I want to add a second tag ID to the pinterest tracking code, so that both can be used for conversion tracking.  Can I call "pintrk('load', 'YOUR_TAG_ID'​);" twice?  Once for each tag id?

https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/ad-tools/conversion-tag/?#basecode

Comment: I think that could work but you'll end up have having same data on both your accounts, why not try to put it and test?

Comment: Documentation is poor. Why not try it?

Comment: The code is on a clients website, and I don't want to interfere with any current operations, so simply giving a try without some reasonable documentation saying it should work would be irresponsible.